# How to supply snakemake options within the Snakefile itself?

Tags: snakemake

I would like to specify singularity bind paths inside the snakefile (ie. snakemake script) and not via command line. I believe this could be done somehow via their api by `from snakemake import something`, etc. How do I achieve this?

*Broadly speaking*, how do we supply options/arguments to snakemake via their api within a Snakefile?

Answer (score 2):

I made a pipeline that does a couple things, and one of those things is download samples. Starting 30 downloads at the same time is a waste of resources so I wanted to limit the number of parallel downloads, and I don't want to always pass `--resources parallel_resources=1` to the command. I noticed that the snakemake.workflow exists when a Snakefile is executed, and here I added this as a resource:

```
workflow.global_resources.update({'parallel_downloads': 1})
```

I have no experience with singularity, so I don't fully understand what you want. But my guess is that this is somewhere stored in the workflow and you can change it there.

p.s. this is not at all through an API, or guaranteed to work between versions